# ES6 namespace import: behavior of "this"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What's the value of `this` in an imported function, which is called from a **namespace import**? (according to the ECMA spec)

```
// module.js
export function fun() {
  return this;
}

// main.js
import * as module from "./module.js";

let x = module.fun(); // What's the value of x here?
```

My guess would be: It's the `module` object, but haven't found a clear answer to this in the spec. Does the normal behavior apply here or is there something special in ES6 modules for namespace imports?

Comment: In Babel it indeed returns the `module` object, however I don't know what the specification says about it.

Comment: Remember that `this` is a property of execution context and not the object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my reading of the spec it would be the module namespace exotic object (which you've bound to the name `module` in your example). In other words, the bag of exports. So in your example I believe you'd be able to call `x.fun()` in the next statement.

As far as I can see...

- The module namespace object would be set as the base value of the reference returned from evaluating the `MemberExpression` in [12.3.2.1 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation)
- The `this` value would just be set as usual in step 5.a.i of the algorithm at [12.3.4.1 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-calls-runtime-semantics-evaluation).

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no special behaviour here. [Module namespaces](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-module-namespace-exotic-objects) may be exotic objects which delegate all accesses to some internals and which are pretty much immutable, but they're still just objects. Method invocations on them don't work different than on any other object.